# Homebrew python3 installation error

Tags: macos, python-3.x, installation, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I was trying to install python 3 using Homebrew by doing `brew install python3` and  there was the warning.

Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall python3`

So I did instead do  `brew postinstall python3`

```==> /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/bin/python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade
dyld: Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Python
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/bin/python3
  Reason: image not found
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Users/dorislee/Desktop/Macintosh HD/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use xcode-select to change
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Users/dorislee/Desktop/Macintosh HD/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use xcode-select to change

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting```

I am not really sure what to do, is there a way to undo this and fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and uninstall `brew remove python3` and then do `brew cleanup` and `brew prune` and then reinstall python3 `brew install python3` with whatever flags you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check your PYTHONPATH variable, clean it, and then try to install python3 anagin